# Disable security for sub path in Apache2

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy, configuration-files

I have a proxy defined in my apache, there is any way to disable security for a sub path. 
In the config I have `/app pointing` to port `localhost:8000` and I want that `/app/public` point to `localhost:8000/public`.

Here is my config file (with security for all paths):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8000
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8000

    ServerName example.com

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Authtype Basic
        Authname "Password Required"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used LocationMatch instead Proxy tag, this is the resulting conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8000
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8000

    ServerName example.com

    <LocationMatch "^(?!/path/to/exclude)/[^/]+">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Authtype Basic
        Authname "Password Required"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```